# Highlight Rows based on InputDate

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I'm new to Excel and I would like to highlight all the rows that are older than my input date.My Spreadsheet is much longer than this example picture, and users might add a row with a new date.

How can I achive this?  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Conditional Formatting. First, don't use a merged cell if you can help it (it looks like your input date is "A and B 85").

Let's say your input date is $A$85, you can go to Conditional Formatting. I'm also going to assume your date data starts in `$P$87`

Highlight row 87 (or just `A87:P87` if you don't want the entire row highlighted).

In Conditional Formatting, use this formula:

`=And($P87<>"",$P87<=$A$85)`

Then click the Format, and go to "Fill", and choose Yellow, or whatever color you want.

Then, change the range the conditional formatting is applied to to say `=$A87:$P1000` to have all rows in between `87` and `1000` highlighted if the date is older than your input date.

[image]

Comment: Alec said:My Spreadsheet is much longer than this example. So I think `conditional formatting` is not a good idea(speed will slower). How about `VBA`?

Comment: @Andy sorry - true, but I'd try CF first because it's also dynamic...but good point, if it's too much data a simple VBA loop may do the trick.